# what does it mean company's subscribers

Tags: meaning

what doest it mean the " susbscriber" in the sentence  "subscribers of the memorandum&Articles of Association were as follow :

Comment: Can't tell without the context. What Association?

Answer (score 1):

> **subscriber**
>   Party that signs a memorandum of association of a new firm and pledges to buy the number of shares written against its name.

http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/subscriber.html

> ‘Subscribers’ are the first shareholders or guarantors in a limited
>   company, i.e. the people who agree to set up the company and whose
>   names are stated on the memorandum of association.

https://www.formationsfactory.co.uk/resources/questions/56b209a1d0614c0e00907c7f/who-is-the-subscriber-to-a-memorandum-of-association

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: subscribers = original shareholders when a company is established.

Articles of association and, optionally, a memorandum, are documents that govern how a business is constituted. From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articles_of_association)

> In corporate governance, a company's **articles of association** (AoA, called articles of incorporation in some jurisdictions) is a document which, along with the memorandum of association (in cases where the memorandum exists) form the company's constitution, defines the responsibilities of the directors, the kind of business to be undertaken, and the means by which the shareholders exert control over the board of directors.

Subscribers are the original shareholders of a company. From [UK Companies House:](https://ewf.companieshouse.gov.uk/help/en/stdwf/webIncHelp.html#subscribers)

> The **subscribers** are the first shareholders of a limited company. A subscriber is a person who subscribes, or puts their name, on the Memorandum of Association and agrees to take up shares in the company at the time of incorporating the company.

Definitions might vary from one country to another but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thnk you Mr.Frank H